# Image align='middle' in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I was wondering if it is possible to align a picture using the align=middle style in CSS, not html.

```
<img alt="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Smiley.png/50px-Smiley.png" align="middle" />Text!
```

Comment: CSS : `vertical-align` middle

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div

Comment: You may need to enclose yor text in a `span` tag http://jsfiddle.net/m4mSY/2/

Comment: what about the god old way : text-align:center on parent or img{display:block;margin:auto;} ?  (attribute align , not valign :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this,

```
img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Use css property `vertical-align:middle;`

Comment: `display:table-cell;` ? why

Answer (score 5):

you are using `align` attribute that in CSS is `float : left;` or `float : right;`

middle won't do anything, you only have option left or right.

For vertical-align, answers have already been given.

to center a single image on a line , you can use on parent : `text-align:center;`, image is an inline-box that reacts like text.

You can as well set image in `display : block;` and `margin : auto;`

Answer (score 0):

```
img { vertical-align: middle; }
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SN6Jp/

Answer (score -2):

You can use `text-align:center;` for the container of the `img` e.g. a `div` and for the image to be aligned vertically at the middle use `vertical-align:middle;` as follows:

### CSS

```
div
{
    text-align:center;
}
img
{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div>
<img alt="" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Smiley.png/50px-Smiley.png"/>Text!
</div>
```

Check this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HXc3q/1/)**

Comment: He wants the image aligned vertically, not in the center.